# homestead подключение библиотек

Tags: php, homestead

Использую виртуальную среду Homestead для локальной разработки и потребовалось подключить библиотеку *GMP*.
Использую:

- php 7.2
- Ubuntu 18

В самой Ubuntu все нужные пакеты присутствуют.
Вопрос как подключить данную библиотеку?

Comment: Непонятно, а вопрос где?

Comment: Модератор зачем-то удалил вопрос... Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописать что нужно установить

**Vagrantfile**

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path "provision/setup.sh"
end
```

**provision/setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Provisioning virtual machine..."
command > /dev/null
```